# How to make the clock rotate correctly?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to implement a 24-hour clock. A clock picture has a pointer around it. How can I turn it?
It rotates 15 degrees for 1 hour.

[image: clock]

I implemented the pointer display by adding a layer.

```
    clockLayer = CALayer()
    clockLayer!.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
    clockLayer!.position = CGPoint(x: 272 * 0.5, y: 272 * 0.5)
    clockLayer!.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 122)
    var imageLayer = CALayer()
    imageLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "home_clock_dot")?.cgImage
    imageLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 122, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
    clockLayer!.addSublayer(imageLayer) 
    clockImageView.layer.addSublayer(clockLayer!)
```

Answer (score 4):

Example: (6am, hour = 6) so you rotate the line by (2 * pi) * (6 / 24)

```
clock.transform.rotated(by: (2 * CGFloat.pi) * (hour / 24))
```

Make sure the anchor point is at the bottom of the line that is "attached" to the clock, so the rotation will happen around that point.

Comment: If I use CATransform3DMakeRotation?  I want to get angle radian.

Comment: Because I have to calculate the radians based on the number of minutes and hours

Comment: @DavisZhang that does calculate the radians based on number of hours so just change the `hour` to hour + (minutes / 60)